# Is it possible to create AWS cloudwatch dashboard for a metric which is not yet emitted?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a cloudwatch dashboard by adding the metrics. However the metrics are not yet emitted. I want use this dashboard for my feature launch. Until feature launches we can't emit metrics. But is there a way to add metric to cloudwatch dashboards before emitting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a metric manually to a dashboard if it cannot be found in search. This [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/add_old_metrics_to_graph.html) explains how to add one manually. Hope it helps.